# Object doesn't support property or method 'nestedSortable'

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, nested-sortable

Having an IE9 issue that is really, really breaking me down mentally. Cannot figure it out! I really hate how we have to deal with these IE issues.

I've gone through about 20 pages on Google looking for an answer and nothing works. I have a form that you can create a "Section". These sections can then be reordered using the jquery nestedSortable plugin.   http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/

In IE9, nothing works. I cannot create sections or reorder them, I get the following error upon loading the page:

SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'nestedSortable'

It states the error has to do with the second character in this:

```
$('#sortable').nestedSortable({
    //disableNesting: 'no-nest',
    listType: 'ul',
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    handle: 'div',
    helper: 'clone',
    items: 'li',
    maxLevels: 2,
    opacity: .6,
    placeholder: 'placeholder',
    revert: 250,
    tabSize: 25,
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    toleranceElement: '> div',
    update: function(){
        order_sections();
    }
});
```

Any ideas? If I completely remove this block of code, I get no errors and I can create sections fine, I can of course not reorder them because this is commented out.

This works great in ALL browser but IE9. Not sure if it works in older version, we only support IE9 because we have to. I wish we could just block all of IE from our application since it is a gigantic garbage dump.

Sorry to come here with a boring IE issue but I'm out of ideas, 3 hours deep into this and I've made no progress.

I do see the compatibility for this plugin is IE6/7/8 and he doesn't mentioned 9.

EDITED***

My javascript files are being included in the footer, here is there order:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/public/website/application.js?v=1362424015"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/public/website/bootstrap.js?v=1364410348"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/public/website/greyScale.js?v=1362424015"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/public/website/jquery.placeholder.js?v=1362424015"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/public/website/jquery.dataTables.js?v=1362424015"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/common/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.min.js?v=1362424015"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/members/global.js?v=1364396131"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.clientsky.com/js/members/proposals/proposal.js?v=1364351236"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/members/proposals/create_proposal_sections.js?v=1365712158"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/common/jquery.mjs.nestedSortable.js?v=1362424015"></script>
```

Everything looks good to me and this is a large application and this is the first time we're seeing a problem like this with one of the plugins.

Comment: When we talk about jquery plugins, this exception most like fires when plugin was not properly loaded. Or it was not loaded yet when you tried to call it. Sorry I can't say more, your piece of code looks ok.

Comment: The page you linked to the plug-in works in IE9, so I assume it is related to implementation, order of execution or similar. How do you load the required scripts, head tag, body tag? Are there any other warnings or errors in the debugger console preceding the one you posted?

Comment: The only other error is: SEC7115: :visited and :link styles can only differ by color. Some styles were not applied to :visited. 
47 which doesn't seem related. I will edit my post above with all the javascript files being included and there order. They're being called in the footer.

Answer (score 1):

Ahh ha solved this, I was loading the javascript file with the above code BEFORE the nestedSortable.js file, just had to switch the two. thanks!